# Modifying QWidget before putting it in QTableWidget

Tags: qt, qwidget

In my QT UI, I need to create a `QTableWidget` in which the user can add a double to each cell.

The table has four columns: the first column is a value from 0-255, the second column to fourth columns are RGB values respectively, each from 0-1.0.

```
void MainWindow::InitializeColorTable(){
        QTableWidget *tableColor = ui->tableColor;
        tableColor->setRowCount(4);
        tableColor->setColumnCount(4);

    tableColor->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QStringList() << 
        tr("Value") << tr("R") << tr("G") << tr("B"));
    for (int row = 0; row < tableColor->rowCount(); ++row){
        tableColor->setCellWidget(row, 0, new QDoubleSpinBox(tableColor));
        tableColor->setCellWidget(row, 1, new QDoubleSpinBox(tableColor));
        tableColor->setCellWidget(row, 2, new QDoubleSpinBox(tableColor));
        tableColor->setCellWidget(row, 3, new QDoubleSpinBox(tableColor));
    }
}
```

I want to modify the properties of my `QDoubleSpinBox` objects, such as set initial values and defining ranges. However, I'm not sure how to do this. If I create `QDoubleSpinBox` objects like

```
QDoubleSpinBox *box = new QDoubleSpinBox;
box->setValue(0);
box->setRange(0, 255);
tableColor->setCellWidget(row, 0, box);
```

in my `InitializeColorTable` function, the `box` variable goes out of scope when the function returns. What is a good way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you decide that the box (QDoubleSpinBox *box = new QDoubleSpinBox;) goes our of scope? This is dynamic object which will become child of tableColor after setCellWidget (only pointer for this object goes out of scope). So do not warry.

Comment: Really? I wasn't aware that QT would automatically manage objects this way. Let me try that out.

Comment: Really:) : void QTableWidget::setCellWidget ( int row, int column, QWidget * widget )
Sets the given widget to be displayed in the cell in the given row and column, passing the ownership of the widget to the table.

If cell widget A is replaced with cell widget B, cell widget A will be deleted. For example, in the code snippet below, the QLineEdit object will be deleted.

Comment: like AnatolyS said, dynamic allocated memory (like `new Foo()`) stays in memory. yeah the pointer `box` goes out of range and if you dont use it you loose the address of the memory `box` is pointing to.